# Menu structure and while loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, menu, flags

so I have encountered a slight problem with my code. Namely, in my menu structure, I have a default option when someone doesn't enter any of the given choices in the menu. So, I'd like for the program to loop the options given until the user enters the correct answer. However, I am not sure whether I quite understand the concept of flags etc, as I keep getting a killer loop during execution. Here's the problem:

```
         else
    {
        while (!choice.equals("a") || !choice.equals("b")||!choice.equals("c"))
        {
            System.out.println("It seems you have made a mistake. Please select one of the options: ");
            System.out.println("a) Create a computer-generated matrix");
            System.out.println("b) Input your own matrix");
            System.out.println("c) Quit");
            choice= kbReader.nextLine();

        }
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your logic.

In english, you have: if "not a" OR "not b" OR "not c".

Let's say that the choice is A. This would create a killer loop as A is "not B" or "not C".

Try changing the code from OR to AND. That way, the while loop needs to test that choice is not A, B, or C to reiterate.

So your first line should be:

```
while (!(choice.equals("a") || choice.equals("b")|| choice.equals("c"))) {
```

Or...

```
while (!choice.equals("a") && !choice.equals("b") && !choice.equals("c"))) {
```

Hope you found it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop logic should be

```
while (!(choice.equals("a") || choice.equals("b")|| choice.equals("c"))) {
            System.out.println("It seems you have made a mistake. Please select one of the options: ");
            System.out.println("a) Create a computer-generated matrix");
            System.out.println("b) Input your own matrix");
            System.out.println("c) Quit");
            choice= kbReader.nextLine();

        }
```